# Error Undefined en Login con IONIC SQLite

Tags: android, angular, ionic, sqlite, crud

Estoy tratando de crear un método de inicio de sesión en IONIC utilizando SQLite mediante una consulta de SELECT COUNT, pero al momento de ingresar los datos da como resultado un error indefinido.

```
public logear(lgm,lgp)
  {
    if (!lgm.length || !lgp.length) 
    {
      alert('No se pueden dejar campos vacios');
      return;
    }
      var cntlog:number;
      this.dbInstance.executeSql(`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Usuarios WHERE Correo ='${lgm}' AND Pass ='${lgp}'`, [cntlog])
      .then((cntlog) => 
      {
        if((cntlog>1))
        {
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs'])
        }
        alert("Las credenciales ingresadas no son correctas")
      }, (e) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(e.err));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Podrías ser más detallado con el error, por favor? Edita tu pregunta

Comment: Digo que estoy intentando un formulario de inicio de sesión en IONIC con SQLite pero no puedo reconocer el error

Comment: A que te refieres con "un error indefinido", cual es el mensaje?, revisaste el Log?

Comment: No puedo acceder al log desde el emulador de cordova

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver estas pasando dentro de los corchetes[] cntlog y eso se utiliza para pasar los parametros en la consulta. Prueba a quitar el cntlog de ahi y que solo esté el de la respuesta de la consulta.( .then((cntlog) => ) y luego cuando haces el if haz un .length para comprobar que tiene datos. La definición de la variable arriba creo que tampoco hace falta.